# Creating a list of items from dropdown menu in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to implement a dropdown where if a choice is made, then it will list the chosen items above the dropdown.

I am using the site below

http://odyniec.net/articles/multiple-select-fields/

The specific section I'm using is below **"Fancy Javascript Method"**, but I put the code in jsfiddle it doesn't work as shown.

Can anyone please help me? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you link us to your fiddle?

Comment: I just directly copied from the website, http://jsfiddle.net/KuY4S/1/

Comment: So, post what you got so far.

Comment: The pepperoni would not show up on list, when i choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned it up a bit, the code was slightly off.

```
function selectIngredient(select) {
    var value = select.val();
    var $ul = $(select).prev('ul');

  if ($ul.find('input[value=' + value + ']').length == 0)
    $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
      value + '" /> ' + value + '</li>');
}

$('select.options').on('change' , function() {
    selectIngredient($(this)); 
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c5s9c/**

Comment: How would I fix the issue where cheese is already selected, and I delete cheese, but can't choose cheese directly because change is not triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <title>Ingredients</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function selectIngredient(select)
    {
      var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      var ul = select.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

      var choices = ul.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
        if (choices[i].value == option.value)
          return;

      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      var text = document.createTextNode(option.firstChild.data);

      input.type = 'hidden';
      input.name = 'ingredients[]';
      input.value = option.value;

      li.appendChild(input);
      li.appendChild(text);
      li.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.parentNode.removeChild(this);');     

      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['ingredients'] ) ) {

    if ( !empty( $_POST['ingredients'] ) ) {

        echo '<fieldset><legend>Your ingredients</legend>';

        foreach ( $_POST['ingredients'] as $ingredient ) {

            echo '<p>- ', $ingredient, '</p>';

        }

        echo '</fieldset>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>No ingredients selected!</p>';

    }

}

?>
<form action="" method="post">

<ul>
 <li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Cheese" />
  Cheese
 </li>
 <li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Ham" />
  Ham
 </li>
 <li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="Mushrooms" />
  Mushrooms
 </li>
</ul>

<select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
 <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
 <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
 <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```